# Retrieve files overwritten by pushing to and pulling from bare repo

Tags: git, git-remote, git-bare

The situation is as follows: there is a bare repo (`repo.git` directory) on a remote Linux server. Up to some point (point A) in the past people had been using it the way prescribed by "bare and non-bare" directive: edit code on your local machine (in the repo that contains `.git` directory) and push it to the remote server. But then they stopped using Git altogether and switched to edit the code directly on the server.

Yesterday (point B) I `git clone` from the remote server, made some changes in the code, committed and then pushed to the server. It turns out that my `git clone` step downloaded to my machine the old code (that was up to date at point A). Then I pushed the old code to the server and then code from point B has been overwritten by code from point A.

Since I've never used Git apart from personal (one-person) project I wonder (and to be honest struggle) whether there is any way to restore point-B-code on the server.

Answer (score 2):

There is no `git` mechanism for recovering versions that were not committed to `git`.  If there is a separate backup, the files can be restored from backup.  (If there is not a separate backup... why would one not back up a server?)

On the one hand, this is another variation on Why I Don't Like Using `git` for Deployment.  On the other hand, if you are going to use git for deployment, then it needs to be understood that nothing other than git should write to the folder to which git deploys, because doing so is just asking to have your work overwritten.  In short: if one's changes are important, why would one not want them preserved with the git history?